# Nested for loops not making desired results

Tags: c++, for-loop

The code makes a text file for every 2 letters. **aa.txt ab.txt ac.txt ad.txt ae.txt af.txt ba.txt bb.txt bc.txt** etcetera, etcetera.

This is simplified version of a larger program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        string letter1;
        if(i = 0){letter1 = "a";}
        if(i = 1){letter1 = "b";}
        if(i = 2){letter1 = "c";}
        if(i = 3){letter1 = "d";}
        if(i = 4){letter1 = "e";}
        if(i = 5){letter1 = "f";}

        for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
        {
            string letter2;
            if(i = 0){letter2 = "a";}
            if(i = 1){letter2 = "b";}
            if(i = 2){letter2 = "c";}
            if(i = 3){letter2 = "d";}
            if(i = 4){letter2 = "e";}
            if(i = 5){letter2 = "f";}

            std::ofstream o(letter1 + letter2 + ".txt");
        }
    }
   return 0;
}
```

The problem is, it completely skips the other letters and only creates **ff.txt**.
I ran across a similar problem while working on another project so it is reoccurring. I never solved that one ether. I personally can not find what could possibly be the problem. Everything seems to be laid out right, but clearly I'm wrong.

Comment: You never do anything with the value of `x`.

Comment: How so? Incrementing it isn't enough I assume.

Answer (score 4):

In your inner for loop, you are checking the value of `i`, not `x`, probably a copy-and-paste error.

It's because of things like this that repetition in code is considered very bad. Whenever you find yourself saying the same thing (or very nearly the same thing) many times over, it pays to think about how you can restructure the code to avoid repeating yourself.

In this case, rather than two if statements, we can put the alternative letters into an array, and loop twice to select the letters we want:

```
int main() {
    static constexpr std::array<char, 6> letters = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            std::cout << letters[i] << letters[j] << ".txt\n"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You use `=` as a comparison symbol, but in C++ `=` is only for assignation. If you want to compare two things together you need to use the `==` operator.

ie :

```
if(i = 5) // wrong ! you set the value of i to 5
if(i == 5) // right ! i == 5 is true when i is in fact equal to 5.
```

And as people pointed out, you need to test for `x` in your second loop, not `i`.